# Splitting a Message into two lines if it's bitgger than a specified length in C

Tags: c

So, i have been trying to re-implement an old technique from sudo for splitting a large message into two lines, original code taken from sudo logging.c:

```c
static void
do_syslog(pri, msg)
    int pri;
    char *msg;
{
    int count;
    char *p;
    char *tmp;
    char save;

    /*
     * Log the full line, breaking into multiple syslog(3) calls if necessary
     */
    for (p = msg, count = 0; count < strlen(msg) / MAXSYSLOGLEN + 1; count++) {
    if (strlen(p) > MAXSYSLOGLEN) {
        /*
         * Break up the line into what will fit on one syslog(3) line
         * Try to break on a word boundary if possible.
         */
        for (tmp = p + MAXSYSLOGLEN; tmp > p && *tmp != ' '; tmp--)
        ;
        if (tmp <= p)
        tmp = p + MAXSYSLOGLEN;

        /* NULL terminate line, but save the char to restore later */
        save = *tmp;
        *tmp = '\0';

        if (count == 0)
        SYSLOG(pri, "%8.8s : %s", user_name, p);
        else
        SYSLOG(pri, "%8.8s : (command continued) %s", user_name, p);

        *tmp = save;            /* restore saved character */

        /* Eliminate leading whitespace */
        for (p = tmp; *p != ' '; p++)
        ;
    } else {
        if (count == 0)
        SYSLOG(pri, "%8.8s : %s", user_name, p);
        else
        SYSLOG(pri, "%8.8s : (command continued) %s", user_name, p);
    }
    }
}
```

However when try the same code with just replacing `syslog` with `printf`, and MAXSYSLOGLEN with 20 instead of 960

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSYSLOGLEN 20

void remake(char *msg){

    int count;
    char *p; 
    char *tmp;
    char save;

    
    for (p = msg, count=0; count < strlen(msg)/MAXSYSLOGLEN + 1; count++){

        if( strlen(p) > MAXSYSLOGLEN) { 

            printf("[*] The message is greater than MAXSYSLOGLEN\n");

            for (tmp = p + MAXSYSLOGLEN; tmp > p && *tmp != ' '; tmp-- );

        if( tmp <= p )
            tmp = p + MAXSYSLOGLEN;

        save = *tmp;
        *tmp = '\0';

        if (count == 0)
            printf("%s\n",p);
        else
            printf("(command continued) %s\n",p );

            *tmp = save;

            for (p = tmp; *p != ' '; p++);
        } else { 
            if (count == 0) 
                printf("%s\n",p);
            else 
                printf("(command continued) %s\n",p );  
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    remake(argv[1]);
}
```

Now to the result:

```
gcc test.c -o test
./test "this is a command ....dklckdsmcsklsmdcdd"
```

```
[*] The message is greater than MAXSYSLOGLEN
this is a command
[*] The message is greater than MAXSYSLOGLEN
(command continued)  ....dklckdsmcsklsmd
(command continued)  ERROR;JS LOG
```

the last line is weird, where does this string even come from ? `ERROR;JS LOG` is it something todo with memory ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** Throw away that awful original code and write your own code from scrath.

**Description**

The bug comes from the original code - here:

```
    /* Eliminate leading whitespace */
    for (p = tmp; *p != ' '; p++)
    ;
```

In case there is no space in the remaining part of the string, `p` will be incremented again and again and will eventually point outside the string. Once `p` points outside the string and you dereference it (i.e. `*p`), you have undefined behavior, i.e. your program can do anything, it can print anything, crash, turn off your computer... anything.

Now look at the comment:

```
    /* Eliminate leading whitespace */
```

Hmmm... but that's not what the code does! It increments `p` as long as there is **no** space. So the code rather "eliminates every thing not being a space" and it doesn't stop when the string ends. Awful.

They probably intended:

```
    /* Eliminate leading whitespace */
    for (p = tmp; *p == ' '; p++)
    ;
```

This will fix many error cases.
But even this will fail for some input... Try it with:

```
"aaa                                               aa"
           ^^^^^^^^
           Lots of spaces, e.g. 100 spaces
```

The spaces will be eliminated but the loop, i.e.

```
for (p = msg, count = 0; count < strlen(msg) / MAXSYSLOGLEN + 1; count++) {
```

isn't adjusted so a number of "unintended" strings will be printed.

As a minor: Note that the comment says "whitespace" but the code only checks for "normal" spaces. The code should have used the `isspace` function.

The only thing to do is: Throw away that awful original code and write your own code from scrath.